# kivy requirements issue buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

im trying to learn kivy so i downloaded kivy virtual machine and copy this hello world app and i run into this problem. i have search the internet but nothing useful 
i tried to upgrade cython
i tried to upgrade the buildozer 
nothing change

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

I edit the buildozer.spec file:

theb run the command **buildozer android debug**

```
kivy@kivyvm:/media/sf_kshared$ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.10 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'pip install -q --user "appdirs" "colorama>=0.3.3" "sh>=1.10,<1.12.5" "jinja2" "six"'
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
# Cwd /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[INFO]:    Using Google NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.6', '4.8', 'clang3.3']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.8
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
[INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements, so one will be built.
[INFO]:    Found multiple valid dependency orders:
[INFO]:        ['hostpython2', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'python2', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:        ['hostpython3crystax', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'python3crystax', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:        ['hostpython2', 'pygame_bootstrap_components', 'python2', 'sdl', 'six', 'pygame', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:    Using the first of these: ['hostpython2', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'python2', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:    The selected bootstrap is sdl2_gradle
[INFO]:    # Creating dist with sdl2_gradle bootstrap
[INFO]:    Dist will have name myapp and recipes (kivy)
[INFO]:    Dist will also contain modules () installed from pip
[INFO]:    -> running cp -r /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/bootstraps/sdl2/build /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootst...(and 30 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2_gradle-python2
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['hostpython2', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'python2', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:    # Downloading recipes 
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    hostpython2 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    sdl2_image download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz
           working: SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz      [INFO]:    sdl2_mixer download already cached, skipping                                                                                                                                     
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading python2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/python2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/python2
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
           working: Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2                                                               [INFO]:    python2 download already cached, skipping                                                                                  
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    sdl2 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading six
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/six
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/six
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.9.0.tar.gz
           working: six-1.9.0.tar.gz                                                                                                                         [INFO]:    six download already cached, skipping                                
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/master.zip
[INFO]:    pyjnius download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading kivy
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/1.10.0.zip
           working: 1.10.0.zip                                                                                                                                                                                     [INFO]:    kivy download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    # Building all recipes for arch armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    # Unpacking recipes
[INFO]:    Unpacking hostpython2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop
[INFO]:    hostpython2 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
                       [INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2_gradle-python2/jni                                                                                    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 978, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 975, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 512, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 149, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 193, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 559, in build_recipes
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 520, in prepare_build_dir
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 422, in unpack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1245, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 633, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 651, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: <exception str() failed>
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_kshared/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
kivy@kivyvm:/media/sf_kshared$
```

**what should i do ?**

Comment: Usually *buildozer* is run without `sudo`. Remove `random` from buildozer.spec. Try `buildozer android debug`

Comment: i did remove random, but still same error

Comment: Are you sharing your Kivy App from local machine with Kivy Buildozer VM?

Comment: ikolim - i did create folder just to share files between VM and the main OS. lets say i didn't share folder thats will effect the building ?

Comment: 1) Create a folder in the Kivy Buildozer VM. 2) Copy your app to that new folder. 3)  cd to-the-new-folder 4) Execute `buildozer android debug`

Comment: ikolim - i did but the same. this not fixing it, when i code a simple app with no requirement, just kivy.app it build and runs okay.

Comment: Please share the complete buildozer log

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BFHmx0AZ here the log - ikolim

Answer (score 0):

> Guys i have solve this problem, what i did is create a new folder in
>   my desktop and make a new spec file and run it and it runs okay.

1) Create a new file on desktop

2) Open Terminal

3) buildozer init >> edit your file

4) buildozer android debug

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but you can try removing everything except kivy from requirements in the buildozer.spec file